# Using ExifReader to find tags property in Jpeg Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, exif

I am trying to get  tags property from my jpeg image as shown in picture.It's value is

```
<tx time=Tue Jul 21 10:20:04 2015> <ocrtime=Fri Jul 31 11:26:09 2015> <plate=4ARS123> <state=CA> <conf=873> <handle=4ARS123> <plateloc=906,744,1326,855>
```

I am trying to get plateloc tag from it and have tried following so far.I understand its one of properties of exiftags which will get me there.which one ? Please help

```
using (ExifReader reader = new ExifReader( Server.MapPath( testimage.ImageUrl )) ){
    // Extract the tag data using the ExifTags enumeration
    string plateloc;
    if (reader.GetTagValue<string>(ExifTags.ExifVersion,
                                    out plateloc))
    {

    }
}
```

[image: I am Trying to get tags part of image properties as show in picture.it has plate loc.]

Comment: Not sure why this question was butchered with edits.

Comment: What is `plateloc`? Googling that only turns up for results, one of which is this question. How did you conclude that your images has those tags?

Comment: plateloc is custom tag attached to image(supposed to be vehicle licence plate location). that tag is supposed to come with my image. atleast that's what my requirement says.

Comment: Ahh. Given your edit, the question makes more sense. It seems that the image has some custom XML stored within the 'Tags' tag. This was confusing before, as the word 'tag' has multiple meanings (in Exif, each value type is known as a tag).

Comment: @DrewNoakes sorry about that!.on other hand I don't have to solve this anymore as my project people decided to put these tags in database instead of image.so I am gonna fetch them from database.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using my [MetadataExtractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/) library.

```
var directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(imagePath);
```

You need to find the correct directory type, and then the correct tag type. With these in hand, you can run code like this:

```
var directory = directories.OfType<MyDirType>().FirstOrDefault();
if (directory != null)
{
    var obj = directory.GetObject(MyDirType.MyTagType);

    // ...
}
```

There are several directories, each with their own tags. Not all directories nor tags are available in all images, and in some cases you may wish to check for the same logical value in multiple physical places.